# First number after parentheses not highlighted in vim

Tags: vim

So I'll have a line in a python file like:

combos = [(1,2,3), (4,5,6)] and the 1 and four will not be highlighted as numbers. This happens with multiple color schemes. I'm wondering how I can fix this.

vimrc at http://pastebin.com/zgmijN9w

Answer (score 0):

Source this function:

```
function! SynStack()
  if !exists("*synstack")
    return
  endif
  echo map(synstack(line('.'), col('.')), 'synIDattr(v:val, "name")')
endfunc
```

and do `:call Synstack()` with the cursor over a number. You are supposed to get `pythonNumber` for all six numbers.

The following command should show you that the highlight group `pythonNumber` is linked to `Number` and where it's done. Presumably in your Python syntax file.

```
:verbose hi pythonNumber
```

If the 6 numbers belong to different highlight groups you should fix your syntax file and/or customize your colorscheme.